# value not send to next UIViewController

Tags: ios, button

Can someone tell me why my values are not being sent from a UIViewController to a UITableViewController?

In my UIViewController I have a number of buttons created programatically and each button has its own tag number set as below:

```
bySeaButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
bySeaButton.tag = 4;
bySeaButton.frame = CGRectMake(20, 294, 280.f, 40.f);
UIImage *seaButton = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gettingHereBySeaButton.png"];
[bySeaButton setBackgroundImage:seaButton forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:bySeaButton];
[bySeaButton addTarget:self action:@selector(bySeaButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then in my prepareForSegue I set the tagVale in my UITableViewController to the buttons tag number as follows:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    MyTableViewController *vc = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];
    vc.tagNumber = bySeaButton.tag;
}
```

A NSLog here shows that the vc.tagNumber is set to the buttons tag number. However, when I access the value for the tagNumber in the UITableViewController, it is always set to 0. Below is how I use it (tagNumber is declared in .m of UITableViewController as @property (nonatomic, assign) int tagNumber;)

```
 NSString *strFromInt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.tagNumber];
```

Output for this is always 0 - regardless of the buttons tag value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in preparesegue

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {

        MyTableViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;

        vc.tagNumber = bySeaButton.tag;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first declare segue id in storyboard ,after add  this method in target

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"push segue id" sender:self];


- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"push segue id"])
    {
        MyTableViewController *vc = [segue   destinationViewControlle];

        vc.tagNumber = bySeaButton.tag;
    }
   }
```